# Does anyone know the API call for picasa after a authorization token is established to get a username/id?

Tags: php, api, picasa

So im using straight php and not the zend framework. Does anyone know what the url call is for accessing or retrieving a list of albums/photos once a auth token is received. After auth token there should some some url that attaches the auth token to it and returns the id user or username so that i can then access there photos. Anyone know what that url is.

Comment: Are you searching for this http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html#ListAlbums ?